# Import microsoft excel comma seperated values to a gridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I have a file upload control that i am using to upload a .csv file which is basically an excel file with type Microsoft Excel comma seperated values. I need to read this file and import the contents onto a gridview.

Before you point me to a solution, 
The challenges I have are :
1) I cannot use an System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader because I cannot refer FilePath, once deployed - the file upload control's file path is not accurate (gives could not find path error) , hence i have to read from **FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream**
2) I cannot use a filereader and parse, because although the extension is .csv, there is no comma delimitation in the file

Please suggest the best possible alternative.

Comment: How exactly are fields seperated from each other?  Note that Excel doesnt "own" the CSV extension - many apps can read and write them - Excel just registers the format making it *seem* like they invented them.  Read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: File is in an excel format with .csv extension

Comment: If it is an "excel format" then it is **not** a CSV.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - your question lacks clarity and much effort

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But please read the first line of my question  "i am using to upload a .csv file which is basically an excel file with type Microsoft Excel comma seperated values." I have tried reading the file with ExcelReader and got the error incorrect signature. Hope I have given you some clarity now. And yes, I have gone thru the How to Ask section clearly.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces, _try something_, then ask a more specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution. 
1) Install ExcelDataReader and ExcelDataReader.Dataset packages from Nuget
2) Use ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader method to read from .csv file which takes input as fileStream
3) Bind the output to gridview

Sample code:

```
Dim reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(fileStream)                                            
Dim result As New DataSet
result = reader.AsDataSet()
DataGridView1.DataSource = result
DataGridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: If it's working, then you have answered your own question and should mark it as the answer. That way if others have the same problem they will know the answer fixes it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing that already, but there is a limitation to wait for 2 days before accepting your own answer.